# ResultObject: Error in getting output (os.path.join to SDE)?

Tags: arcpy, raster, enterprise-geodatabase, file-geodatabase, copy

I have a scratch FileGeodatabase where I do some raster processing...

```
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace  = r'C:\test\scratch.gdb'
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.env.scratchGDB
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
```

I have a SDE connection that is my final output location...

```
folder_path = r'C:\test\testfolder'
test_SDE = arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management(folder_path,
                                                   out_name='SDEconnection',
                                                   database_platform='SQL_SERVER',
                                                   instance='test_instance',
                                                   account_authentication='OPERATING_SYSTEM_AUTH',
                                                   database='test_database',
                                                   version_type='TRANSACTIONAL',
                                                   version='dbo.default')
```

I'm using arcpy.copyRaster_management to copy raster datasets out of my scratchGDB into the SDE...

```
arcpy.CopyRaster_management(rasteroutput, os.path.join(test_SDE, "testSDEraster"))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
<class 'arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjects.Result'>
ResultObject: Error in getting output
```

How do I copy the raster datasets into my SDE? I think it has something to do with the os.path.join.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "unpack" the result object with getOutput(0) per the [docs](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/result.htm)

try:

```
arcpy.CopyRaster_management(rasteroutput, os.path.join(test_SDE.getOutput(0), "testSDEraster"))
```